# Needed a suggestion on how to take up the sqlite existing databse and connect to the django application to prepare rest api

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Needed a suggestion on how to take up the sqlite existing databse and connect to the django application to prepare rest api. Database contains images and descriptions.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This below link having a definitive guide for starters who want to develop projects with RESTful APIs using Python, Django and Django Rest Framework.

https://github.com/crudlio/crudl-example-django